# Use own html template or forms in Django 1.10

Tags: django, forms, django-templates

I have to use a form in a template. But i have the HTML markup already.
How can i replace the inputs on my html without loosing my styles?

**UPDATE**

I finally did it. (sorry for source in spanish)

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

class formularioContacto(forms.Form):
    nombre = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'required': True, 'name': 'nombre', 'class': 'validate', 'for': 'nombre'}))
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'required': True, 'name': 'email', 'class': 'validate', 'for': 'email'}))
    mensaje = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'required': True, 'name': 'mensaje', 'class': 'materialize-textarea', 'for': 'mensaje'}))

#Changing label names
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(formularioContacto, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['nombre'].label = "Tu nombre: *"
    self.fields['email'].label = "Tu correo: *"
    self.fields['mensaje'].label = "Escribí tu mensaje acá: "
```

**HTML file**

```
<form action="." method="post">
<div class="row jsSubmit_button">

    {% for field in form %}

    {% if field.name == "nombre" %}
    <div class="input-field col-md-6">
        {{ field }}
        <label>
            <i class="zmdi zmdi-account"></i>{{ field.label }}
        </label>
    </div>
    {% elif field.name == "email"%}
    <div class="input-field col-md-6">
        {{ field }}
        <label>
            <i class="zmdi zmdi-email"></i>{{ field.label }}
        </label>
    </div>
    {% else %}
    <div class="input-field col-md-12">
        {{ field }}
        <label><i class="zmdi zmdi-border-color"></i>{{ field.label }}
        </label>
    </div>
    {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <button type="submit" class="th_bt btn waves-effect" name="submit_btn">
            Enviar<i class="zmdi zmdi-mail-send"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you need to keep the HTML absolutely identical, you'll have to keep it all manual.

Comment: Im trying to do it again, I will update the post in a minute.

Comment: You can always use `{{ field.label_tag }}` and `{{ field.value }}` — https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually